# Encountered an error while compiling cobalt on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, ninja, cobalt

While compiling cobalt for raspberry pi on ninja, im getting an error like this:

`undefined reference to symbol 'eglCreateImageKHR'`

here is the full trace:

`[1/1] LINK cobalt
FAILED: cobalt 
/home/mi07/work/raspitools/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ @cobalt.rsp
/home/mi07/work/raspitools/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: obj/starboard/raspi/2/../shared/open_max/starboard_platform.decode_target_create.o: undefined reference to symbol 'eglCreateImageKHR'
/home/mi07/work/raspitools/sysroot/opt/vc/lib/libbrcmEGL.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.`

I googled it and found somewhat related article on this [site](https://github.com/jvcleave/ofxOMXPlayer/issues/115).

As per this article the fault could be that of `libssl1.0-dev` not being there. I checked and found it was `libssl-dev`. Replaced it with libssl1.0-dev but still the error persists.

Can somebody tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

eglCreateImageKHR() is an EGL extension [EGL_KHR_image](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_image_base.txt). Since Cobalt compiled, it appears the headers declare the extension, but the linked EGL library didn't define it. It's surprising that only eglCreateImageKHR() is missing and not eglDestroyImageKHR as well.

At any rate, I recommend trying to update the EGL library, but I'm not familiar with the raspi install, so can't tell you the specifics.

Alternatively, it is safe to comment out the call to that function in decode_target_create.cc since SbImageIsDecodeSupported() always returns false for raspi (see image_is_decode_supported.cc), so decode targets should never be created / destroyed on the platform. (Decode target support is a work in progress for raspi.)

Comment: I commented those and that part worked fine but stumbled up on another error like following
`undefined reference to  <some function call> @GLIBCXX_3.4.21`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing the os itself. The problem was that the cobalt was not compatible with raspi stretch but with raspi jessie. Because `sysroot` files are being copied from the OS it was creating that error. I don't know exactly where the difference is but changing to raspi jessie worked fine for me.